# "Am Ort" vs "Im Ort"

Tags: grammar, preposition

> Ich gehe an den Ort, wo ich mir die Haare schneiden lasse.
>
> Das ist der Ort, an dem ich geboren bin

Why does the word "Ort" always uses the preposition "an"? If one uses "in" with Ort will it be wrong?

Comment: Nein. z.B. "In diesem Ort wurde ich geboren." - "Die Schänke befindet sich mitten im Ort."

Comment: @Ingo How do you know whether to use in or an?

Comment: @thekeyofgb "am Ort" uses "Ort" in the more abstract sense of "point", "location", "place", while with "im Ort" it is in the sense "settlement", "village", "town" - another word is "Ortschaft"

Comment: @thekeyofgb Hence you could say "An diesem Ort wurde ich geboren." for example when you are pointing to the clinic where you were born.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's just how it goes. Could be "zu"/"bei" in a different universe and that would make just as much sense.
There is also "in" + Ort. Then, "Ort" means something like "village".

> Im Ort 30 fahren.
>
> 30 mph inside the settlement (no idea what the English phrasing is)